# How to maintain Thread context across async await model in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, threadstatic

Is using ThreadStatic and setting the context every time await completes "an option"? Is there another way?

```
public async void Test()
{
    // This is in Thread 1
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Context.context = "context1"; // This is ThreadStatic
    string result = await foo.CallAsynx();

    // This is most likely Thread 2
    Context.context = "context1";   // This might be a different thread and so resetting context    
}
```

Now is there another way if I don't want to use ThreadStatic?

Comment: Do you really need thread `ThreadStatic`? You can flow your global state variables via `CallContext.LogicalSetData`/`LogicalGetData`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22363830/1768303

Comment: Or you could change it to `foo.CallAsynx(context);`. That's the way ASP.NET MVC went.

Comment: Besides, async does not create a new thread. I would go with Paulo's aproach. In a ASP.NET context, (Thread)Static is NOT safe, different requests are run on threads from the threadpool, so (thread)static variables will survive and be shared between reqeusts/users

Comment: I want to avoid ThreadStatic which is the reason for asking this question :). Also, a thing to consider is if the await call throws an exception, the logic I put in would not work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ThreadStatic`, `ThreadLocal<T>`, thread data slots, and `CallContext.GetData` / `CallContext.SetData` do not work well with `async`, since they are thread-specific.

The best alternatives are:

1. Passing it as an argument as @PauloMorgado suggested. Equivalently, you could set it as a field member of an object (it's implicitly passed as an argument via `this`); or you could have your lambdas capture the variable (underneath, the compiler will implicitly pass it as an argument via `this`).
2. Use `HttpContext.Items` (if you are on ASP.NET 4.5).
3. Use `CallContext.LogicalGetData` / `CallContext.LogicalSetData` as @Noseratio suggested. You can only store immutable data in the logical thread context; and it only works on .NET 4.5 and is not available on all platforms (e.g., Win8).
4. Force all `async` continuations back to the same thread by installing a "main loop" for that thread, such as the [`AsyncContext` from my AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext).

Comment: I was experimenting with CallContext.LogicalGetData and CallContext.LogicalSetData and looks like that will work for our scenario. Also, Stephen - I came across your blog on "Implicit Async context". Great blog. Do you know how is LogicalGetData/LogicalSetData designed internally? I hope its not using ThreadStatic :)

Comment: No, it's not using `ThreadStatic`. :) The "logical call context" is [part of the execution context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx) that is (shallow) copied by the framework as your code "flows" to other threads. In .NET 4.5, the logical call context got copy-on-write behavior, which enables it to work as expected for asynchronous code.

Comment: Stephen, re:"and it only works on .NET 4.5 and is not available on all platforms (e.g., Win8)." do you mean WinPho 8?

Comment: @Mike: Actually, I was referring to Windows 8 Store Apps. However, I believe this will also not work on Windows Phone.

Comment: Will CallContext.LogicalGetData work on ASP.NET Applications running in Azure?

Comment: @Triynko: It should, as long as you're using .NET 4.5 or above.

Comment: Just want to mention here, that since .Net 4.6 there is an `AsyncLocal<T>` appear to solve this problem

Comment: @StephenCleary, where can I read more about the copy-on-write behavior introduced on .NET 4.5? and thanks for all your great posts!

Comment: @Tamir I have an [old blog post here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). Other than that, your best approach is [the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs,968). :/

Answer (score 11):

Just if someone has the same question some years later and finds this thread...

There is a new feature called

```
AsyncLocal<T>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netcore-3.1

This works with "async/await" and also with:

- Task.Run(...)
- Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)
- new Thread(...).Start()

I just testet those three with the following code:

```
    private void StartTests() {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Task.Run(() => DoWork1());
        Task.Run(() => DoWork2());
    }

    private void DoWork1() {
        ThreadContext.Context.Value = "Work 1";
        Thread.Sleep(5);
        Task.Run(() => PrintContext("1"));
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => PrintContext("1")));
        Thread.Sleep(15);
        var t = new Thread(() => PrintContextT("1"));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void DoWork2() {
        ThreadContext.Context.Value = "Work 2";
        Task.Run(() => PrintContext("2"));
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => PrintContext("2")));
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        var t = new Thread(() => PrintContextT("2"));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void PrintContext(string c) {
        var context = ThreadContext.Context.Value;
        Console.WriteLine("P: " + context + "-" + c);

        Task.Run(() => PrintContext2(c));
    }

    private void PrintContext2(string c) {
        Thread.Sleep(7);
        var context = ThreadContext.Context.Value;
        Console.WriteLine("P2: " + context + "-" + c);
    }

    private void PrintContextT(string c) {
        var context = ThreadContext.Context.Value;
        Console.WriteLine("T: " + context + "-" + c);
    }

    public class ThreadContext {
        public static AsyncLocal<object> Context = new AsyncLocal<object>();
    }
```

Output:

P: Work 2-2

P: Work 1-1

P2: Work 2-2

P: Work 2-2

P2: Work 1-1

P: Work 1-1

P2: Work 2-2

T: Work 2-2

P2: Work 1-1

T: Work 1-1